# QGIS does not remember paths to previous projects after restarting computer

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I am running QGIS 2.18 on Ubuntu 16.02. After turning on my computer and opening QGIS I see that QGIS will not remember the paths to previously opened projects.  I can see a thumbnail of these projects and the paths to these projects.  To open them I need to track down the project through *File - Open* rather than select it from the list of recently opened projects.

If I have a QGIS project open, then close QGIS but do not turn off the computer, I can reopen QGIS select a project from the recent projects list.

Why does QGIS not remember the paths to my recent projects and how can I fix this annoying behavior?   I have not notice this behavior with any other software installed.